# How to update an Access VBA app with 30 forms?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I need to update an Access VBA app with around 30 forms in it.

I have to amend a screen that seems to have been set up right at the start of the app, it uses a lot of SQL tables. Is there an way of finding my way to the start of the code?

I come from a procedural coding background and I am unused to code that doesn't have a start and an end; I also know a bit of VB, some ASP, some .Net and general computing.

Answer (score 1):

When something "automagically" happens upon opening an Access database, it is almost always because

1. A "startup form" has been specified. (In Access_2010 that's done in `File > Options > Current Database > Display Form`.)   ***...or...***
2. The database has a Macro named `AutoExec` which is automatically run when the database is opened (unless you bypass it by holding the [Shift] key down while opening).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Gord's answer, there's a few things you need to know. I'm going to give you the quick & dirty version.

First, there's 2 types of code in Access. VBA & macros. Sometimes  what's called a macro, is really VBA.

- In Access, a macro is a set of instructions to do something to the database. It's very limited in what it can do.  These are often used by novices who don't know how to program in VBA.
- VBA is the real powerhouse behind the scenes. It can do everything a macro can do, but a whole lot more.

Access uses an **Event-Driven** / **Object-Oriented** (at least close enough for this discussion) interface. Do a Google search on those meanings.  But very quickly, the listbox on a form is an object. It has **properties** (like width), **methods** (add an item), and **events** (click on an item).

To see the code, for macros look to to your navigation window to your left. For VBA (modules), look to the same window, or just press Alt-F11. VBA can be used standalone in a module, or behind the scenes of a form or report.

Once you get the hang of it, you'll find Access to be a handy RAD tool for small projects.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you already have found the form that opens when the app starts *(if not, check out Gord Thompson's answer)*.

The first things that happen when an Access Form opens  (the "start of the code", as you called it) are the `Load` and `Open` events.
If there is any code in this form that is connected to these events, then it's in the `Form_Load()` and `Form_Open()` functions in the code of the form.